# How do I fix 'OperationalError at /admin/' when I push a Django project to Heroku?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, heroku

I am following a tutorial online and have no problem viewing and accessing my admin panel in Django's test server. I can edit models there. It's when I pushed my project to Heroku and trying to access the admin panel from there, I get this error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/
no such table: django_session
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://gentle-lowlands-8347.herokuapp.com/admin/
Django Version: 1.8.1
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: django_session
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 318
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.9
Python Path:    
['/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-16.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python27.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 28 May 2015 11:14:19 +0000
```

I think it may have been a problem when I tried to run: `heroku run python mange.py syncdb`

I created a super user. Try to access the admin panel nothing works.

I feel like it has something to do with migrating my database and something in my settings.py file that is wrong.  I really have no clue.  I have been researching and messing around with it for days.

If some can take a look and help me out: https://github.com/jltsao88/coffeedapp

Comment: Can you confirm that your database is setup correctly? Which db you use?

Comment: I am not sure how to confirm is the database is set up correctly.  Django comes set with sqlite3 and I was supposed to migrate it to heroku which uses postgres

Comment: Also, I am following the Django tutorial with a windows computer and the tutorial does it with a mac.  I noticed some things were different like when I  did pip install postgres my computer installed postgres 2.1.2 whereas when the tutorial did pip install postgres it installed postgressql 9.x or something

Answer (score 0):

In your settings, ON_HEROKU will never actually be equal to True, because environment variables are always strings. This means that your db settings will never be set.

Instead you should just check for boolean truth:

```
if ON_HEROKU:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because Django cannot find the table `django_session` in order to write the session into it. In my experience this happens have not run `migrate` or the table has been manually deleted.

I would advise you to check the following:

- Your `settings.py` file to check that `DATABASES` show the proper database that Heroku provides.
- Access the database yourself with the appropriate credentials, the ones that you specify in your `settings`, to see if the database is accessible.
- Make sure that you have run `manage.py migrate`.

I am not familiar with the Heroku services but I am certain that they provide some sort of documentation on how to setup and access a database for your app.

It may also be possible that you maintain a separate `settings.py` file for your dev server and for your live server.

Comment: I ran both python manage.py migrate and everything is fine on my test server. When I first tried to go into admin in the heroku app I got to log in the admin page but not see my Location model.  After I tried messing around with things and could not ever get to log in as admin and the operational error page came up.  Is there a way to look into the database to see if it synced on heroku?

Comment: No idea; I tried to give you a viewpoint from Django's perspective. You would have to check with Heroku for how to use their services. Possibly https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql